# How to create a string of int from a file C

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, integer

I have a `file.csv` that contains a pair of int divided by a comma.
My goal is to read the numbers from the file (`fgets`) and put them in `char (*arr)` , like strings.
The problem is that it adds more numbers after the comma.
How can I do?

> Example
> this number: 9514902,846
> in arr: 9514902,845962

**main.c**

```
#define SIZE 10
#define LEN 20


int main(){
    char (*arr)[LEN] = NULL;
    int pos = 0;
    FILE *fd = NULL;

    fd = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    arr = calloc ( SIZE, sizeof *arr);

    while ( pos < SIZE && fgets ( arr[pos], sizeof arr[pos], fd)) {
        printf ("%s", arr[pos]);
        ++pos;
    }

    fclose ( fd);
    free ( arr);

    return 0;
}
```

**file.csv**

```
9514902,846
1134289,572
7070279,994
30886,48552
750704,1169
1385812,729
471548,3595
8908491,196
4915590,362
375309,212
```

**my output:**

```
9514902,845962
1134289,571587
7070279,993574
30886,485520
750704,116888
1385812,729300
471548,359462
8908491,19559
4915590,361558
375309,211958
```

Comment: Why make it more complex than needed? If you don't mind the comma, just read the entire line into the array element.

Comment: After this I will have to work on each string. I need the right value. @SouravGhosh

Comment: So, to make it clear, you want the output to be `9514902,846` as string, right? or you want to get rid of the comma and concatenate the two int values?

Comment: I have tried your code and after get rid of an extra } it outputted as expected. What compiler do you use?

Comment: Yes, I want the output to be `9514902,846` as string. @SouravGhosh

Comment: It is true, there is an extra }, sorry. The problem is that the output (the numbers) is wrong. @Kozmotronik

Comment: Here is my output with the same code: [ismail-teknimer@teknimer-fedora Karalama]$ gcc -Wall file.c
[ismail-teknimer@teknimer-fedora Karalama]$ ./a.out
9514902,846
1134289,572
7070279,994
30886,48552
750704,1169
1385812,729
471548,3595
8908491,196
4915590,362
375309,212

Comment: I don't understand why it is different from mine. I use CLion. @Kozmotronik

Comment: Does your file have Windows style CRLF line endings and you're running this on Linux or another OS with LF line endings? Or vis versa?

Comment: I am on Windows. @Shawn

Comment: I have only one file in the folder. I also tried to put all the path. @user3121023

Comment: It's true, thanks. @user3121023

Comment: That I have not put the controls @user3121023

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code easier to write, maintain and understand. As I see, you don't need the dynamic memory allocation, either.

Change to

```
#define SIZE 10
#define LEN 20


int main(){
    char arr[LEN] = {0};   // just define a char array, should be sufficient.
    int pos = 0;
    FILE *fd = NULL;

    fd = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    if (!fd) {                          // don't for get the error check
        printf ("File handling error\n");
        exit (-1);
    }

    while ( pos < SIZE && fgets ( arr[pos], LEN, fd)) {
        printf ("%s", arr[pos]);
        ++pos;
    }

    fclose ( fd);
}
```

Comment: I have a file with 6 million records. I put a piece to show how it works. I need to dynamically allocate it.

Comment: @Banana Then you should really re-think your strategy, with 6M records and allocating  memory dynamically, you're likely to fail the allocator function calls.

Comment: `char arr[SIZE][LEN]`, surely?

Comment: Also with this the output remains the same. @Shawn